# Java Class.forName() vs Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass()

Tags: java, class, static

Can someone explain me the difference between Class.forName() and Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(). 
I have next code

```
<code>
public class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello from static block");
         }
}

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
//Class test = Class.forName("com.home.Test"); //Outputs "Hello from static block"
  Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.home.Test");
}
}
</code>
```

And when i execute  Class.forName("com.home.Test") it outputs "Hello from static block". But when i execute Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.home.Test"); it outputs nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ClassLoader.loadClass(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#resolveClass%28java.lang.Class%29) does not resolve the class (and thus does not initialize it either).

[`Class.forName(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) on the other hand *does* initialize the class. This is why you see the initializers being run in that case, but not when using `loadClass`.

The load/link/initialize steps are described in the JSL in the [Excecution](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html) section if you want the details (it's an interesting read).